# How to scale values without using log for plotting curves of different ranged values in the same figure in python?

Tags: python, dataframe, plot, scale

I'm trying to plot a comparison between different column values of a DataFrame. But one of the column values is so low that it's plotting as a straight line though it's a curve. The code is given below:

```
fig=go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x = df_plot["Dates"], y = (df_plot["A"]))

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x = df_plot["Dates"], y = (df_plot["B"]))

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x = df_plot["Dates"], y = (df_plot["C"]))

fig.update_layout(height = 600, width = 1100,
                 xaxis_title="Date",yaxis_title="Cases",legend=dict(x=0,y=1,traceorder="normal"))
fig.show()
```

The 'C' column colored red has significantly smaller values than the other two. The output is follows:
[image]

I've scaled using log but the result isn't much satisfactory as it changes the curves trend. The output using log scaling is as follows:
[image]

So, is there any way except using log to scale them so that I could visualize them properly?

Comment: You can plot 10 times the value, or maybe 100 times the value of the red line? bit hacky I guess, but should do the job. If you wanna do it more properly, you'd have to add another axis on the right, and make clear some way that that axis is for the red line only

Comment: It seems you are plotting cases of something, maybe you can normalize them by population size or something like that.

Comment: Thanks @Leander, but, I've already tried multiplying the values of the 'C' column but it doesn't do the job properly. But the extra axis thing you suggested seems interesting. Can you share some resources of how do that in python?

Comment: I've only done this in matplotlib, but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65037641/plotly-how-to-add-multiple-y-axes) seems to handle the question for plotly. It uses a different setup to plot the lines though, but I don't think you're too attached to your method of plotting